# Select com group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero agrupar os resultados que tenham o mesmo `name(varchar)` e contar o `value(int)` dos diferentes `key_id(varchar)`.

Exemplo, se os registos fossem esses:

[image: registros]

Os resultados seriam esses(lembrando que o valor `key_id` é "randomico"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O único jeito que eu conheço de fazer isso exclusivamente com SQL seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT (
        'SELECT name, ',        
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT CONCAT(
                '(',
                    'SELECT IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) '
                    'FROM tabela b ',
                    'WHERE b.key_id = "', key_id, '"',
                    'AND b.name = a.name'
                ') ', key_id, ' '
            )
        ), ' '
        'FROM tabela a ',
        'GROUP BY name'
    ) INTO @sql
FROM tabela;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Repare que são 3 statements (o primeiro gera uma query, o segundo "prepara" o statement, e o terceiro executa a query).

Apesar disso funcionar, eu só recomendaria usar isso se for pra gerar algum relatório, ou pra uma base de dados bem pequena, jamais em uma aplicação, porque para algumas centenas de key_ids, o BD já não engoliria bem.

A melhor solução seria obter todos os dados da tabela e agrupar conforme o que você precisa no lado da aplicação (usando node/PHP/C#/Java, o que for).

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro que tente o seguinte:

```
select sum(value) 
from nome_da_tabela 
group by name, key_id
```

Os registos de soma 0 não estarão no resultset, porém antes de apresentar os dados em formato tabular, preencha com 0 (zero) as células que ficarem vazias.

Comment: Poderia melhorar suas resposta, utilizando formatação veja [Como formatar minhas publicações usando o Markdown ou HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Isto resulta em múltiplos resultados com o mesmo "Name".

Comment: Certamente. Mas este é o resultado correto usando apenas SQL. Você deverá em seguida trabalhar o resultset para apresentar os dados sem a repetição do "name". É boa prática manter separado o código-fonte da camada de apresentação.